# LTL Model of (infinitely often p) ∧ ( infinitely often q) ∧ (¬ Eventually (p ∧ q))?

Tags: formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic

Can anyone give a model of the following LTL formula?
$$
\Box\Diamond p \land \Box\Diamond q \land \lnot \Diamond (p \land q).
$$
That is, we want each of $p$ and $q$ to hold infinitely often, but $p \land q$ should never hold.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Shaull  The invariant is confusing me but I think a formula such as π = {p}{q}{p}{q}{p}{q}.... but i'm really  not sure.

Comment: Not sure what invariant you're talking about, but $\pi$ as you suggest indeed satisfies the formula.

Comment: @Shaull i mean im confused with this part of the formula  (¬ Eventually (p ∧ q)). Does it mean that p and q can never be together like {p}{q} or does it mean {p,q}?

Comment: The latter. It means that the current letter never satisfies both $p$ and $q$, i.e. it is not $\{p,q\}$.

Comment: Yes, _Eventually φ_ means that in some state reachable in a finite number of steps _φ_ is true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $p$ to mean even number, $q = \neg p$ meaning odd number.

Can you come up with a model where you have infinitely often $p$ and infinitely often $q$ but never both at the same time?